# bootstrap 3 justified button group has a tiny gap underneath drop-down button, while within navigation tabs

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, tabs, buttongroup

I am trying to have a justified button group, within the navigation tabs, to display correctly, with Bootstrap 3.3.7. Everything looks good when the button group is outside of the navigation tabs.  But as soon as I put the button group within a navigation tab, there would be a small gap underneath the "Dropdown" button, on Windows Chrome. Here is a sample code, and the gap goes away as soon as I delete the entire "remove_me" element.  Is there anyway to remove the small gap underneath the "Dropdown" button within the navigation tab, while using any browser like Windows Chrome? Or what's wrong with the code that it would generate a small gap underneath the "Dropdown" button? Thanks in advance!

[Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/nhk93oma/)

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LW4e.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
    <div name="remove_me" class="row">
        <div class='col-md-7'>
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class='active'><a href="#main" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">main tab</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sub" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">sub tab</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Left</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Middle</a>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span> </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">extra button to show gap above this button</a></div>
                    There is a gap underneath the "Dropdown" button.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="sub">sub tab content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj4zkLmu/).
Just try this line of css.

```
.dropdown-menu{
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but there still is a tiny gap between drop-down and extra buttons. Probably because I am using Chrome. There wouldn't be any gap to begin with, if using IE. I am going to add that info to my question, sorry, but thanks for trying.

Comment: xam, can you make an screenshot of the gap because for me it's fine and I don't see any gap underneath the "dropdown"?

Comment: It is kind of strange that only me seeing the gap... I added the sample image on my question, thank you for identifying and shed some light on this subject matter.

Comment: @xam, maybe you are viewing in browser with 110% view or larger? Try to press cmd + 0

Comment: I don't have cmd button, but I tried Ctrl + 0, but nothing happened. My browser setting is zoom view to 100%, originally, thanks

Comment: Please try to set outline: none. If this won't work too then I don't know what to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146462/discussion-between-david-khasikyan-and-xam).

Comment: probably the problem persist on Windows Chrome, I'll need to add that info on my original question, thank you very much, to help me understand the problem more

Comment: I found the problem is that my windows display settings were 125%, and the gap would appeared on chrome when windows display setting is on 125% (Medium). Thank you for noticing the viewing size weren't 100%, and you were on the par. While this could be a chrome bug, I mark you as the correct answer. Thank you again!